# TCP Socket Client\Server Request Response

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcpclient

I'm developing a .Net 4.5.2 windows TCP socket master\client messaging solution. The solution is working for the most part; however I need the server to send a response message back to the client when the send button is selected. When the connect button is selected the master does successfully send a response message back to the client.  I have made numerous attempts to send the response message back to the client application from the master when the send button is selected, but I have been unable to make it work.  I am looking for some help to get me moving forward again.  Don’t want to keep spinning my wheels and making no progress.  Thanks in advance for the help.  Please find below the server and client solutions:

Server Code:

```
 public partial class ServerForm : Form
    {
        private Socket serverSocket;
        private Socket clientSocket; // We will only accept one socket.
        private byte[] buffer;

        public ServerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartServer();
        }

        private static void ShowErrorDialog(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        private void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.124");
                serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 4545));
                serverSocket.Listen(10);
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
                buffer = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                var sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
                clientSocket.BeginSend(sendData, 0, sendData.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendCallback, null);
                clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket.EndSend(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int received = clientSocket.EndReceive(AR);

                if (received == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                PersonPackage person = new PersonPackage(buffer);
                SubmitPersonToDataGrid(person);

                clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);

                //Added BeginSend which answered my question.  Simple enough fix.  Thanks for looking...
                byte[] sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(person.Name);
                clientSocket.BeginSend(sendData, 0, sendData.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendCallback, null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Client Code:

```
 public partial class ClientForm : Form
    {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private byte[] buffer;

        public ClientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void ShowErrorDialog(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                int received = clientSocket.EndReceive(AR);

                if (received == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).TrimEnd('\0');

                Invoke((Action) delegate
                {
                  textBoxEmployee.Text = string.Empty;
                  textBoxEmployee.Text = "Server says: " + message +  " Paul";
                });

                clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
            }

            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket.EndConnect(AR);
                UpdateControlStates(true);
                buffer = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket.EndSend(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateControlStates(bool toggle)
        {
            Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                buttonSend.Enabled = toggle;
                buttonConnect.Enabled = !toggle;
                labelIP.Visible = textBoxAddress.Visible = !toggle;
            });
        }

        private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PersonPackage person = new PersonPackage(checkBoxMale.Checked, (ushort)numberBoxAge.Value, textBoxEmployee.Text);
                byte[] buffer = person.ToByteArray();
                clientSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendCallback, null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
                UpdateControlStates(false);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
                UpdateControlStates(false);
            }
        }

        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                // Connect to the specified host.
                var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBoxAddress.Text), 4545);
                clientSocket.BeginConnect(endPoint, ConnectCallback, null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Found issue.  Added `BeginSend` to server `SendCallBack` method.  Code has been updated and works...